# Whats the prefered way to get an immutable observable?

Tags: angular, observable, immutability

When I subscribe into observable and alter the received data, the data in observable is changed without calling observable.next();

That's not the expected behavior?

```
const jobs = this._jobService.jobs.value;

this.jobs = _.chain(jobs)
        .filter(j => j.status === 2)
        .map(j => {
          j.facility = _.findWhere(facilities, {_id: j.facility});
          return j;
        })
        .first(3)
        .value();

this._jobService.jobs.value; // shows the altered data
```

The only thing I found is using

```
const jobs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this._jobService.jobs.value));
```

But that looks ugly and feels wrong.

How you solve this issue?

Comment: Where do you subscribe? Subscribe in component and do whatever there to the variable you assign the data.

Comment: Your example doesn't have any observables. And I'm not sure about the significance of _"the data in observable is changed without calling observable.next();"_. Anyway: You use a library that allows you to clone objects.